# Why was dependency injection pattern not included in the Gang of four?

Tags: design-patterns

Why was the dependency injection pattern not incluided in the [gang of four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)? Did GOF pre-date widespread automated testing? Is dependency injection now considered a core pattern?

Comment: .. because "Dependency injection" is *not a pattern!*

Comment: @DipanMehta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823387/is-dependency-injection-just-another-name-for-the-strategy-pattern

Comment: Everything that gets repeated forms a pattern of repetition.  **All** design elements (that aren't unique, crazy ideas) are "patterns".

Comment: Books are always products of their time. I'd lay good money on it (and the closely-related _IoC_) being a key pattern if you were doing such a book now.

Comment: These long responses are probably misleading, as they kind of validate the question. While, as mentioned, dependency injection is not a design pattern. It is a "mechanism" for object instantiation, typically handled by the framework.

Comment: Dependency injection **is a pattern**. It *opposes* the Service Locator pattern. Read [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) who coined the term. I have absolutely no idea how so many people upvoted such nonsense.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I was Editor of *Software Development* magazine when the Gang of Four book came out and I can say with total confidence that unit-testing was not a widespread practice in 1994, when *Design Patterns* was originally published.

In 1994, C++ was the most commonly used object-oriented language, and most people programming it were coming from a C background. One of the "thinking in objects" things that people simply didn't have is the idea of hundreds or thousands of entry points into your program. You thought about the `main()`. If you worked on a large project, you might have a (usually quite elaborate) makefile to create a module-based program. But "unit-testing"? Starting a process, building the necessary memory context, executing it, and tearing it down, on a *per method* basis? That was very radical.

Java made multiple-entry-point programming more obvious. By the time of the original Dot-Com boom, unit-testing was a well-known technique, but it was really JUnit (circa 2001?) that caused it to catch fire and become a universal practice.

Although *Strategy* and the general concept of programming to an interface were part of GoF and the mid-90s zeitgeist, the idea of *injection* came quite late to the party (circa '03-'05?). Honestly, my gray hairs are still quite dubious about that aspect of DI ("Get off my lawn, you darn configuration files!").

Comment: I regret that I only have but one up vote to give for such an insightful answer.

Comment: @Larry OBrien: scanning for convention based registrations vastly simplifies configuration code and practically eliminates xml configuration in ioc containers.

Comment: I would like to add that dependency injection at its core does not rely on configuration files at all. You can do it all by hand, which makes it very easy to use and is still a very flexible approach.

Answer (score 34):

They called it **Strategy**.

Their Strategy seems to have all the features of dependency injection without the complex-sounding name.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense actually. +1

Comment: I don't see a connection between the Strategy pattern and Dependency Injection. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: -1. Sorry! Strategy pattern has nothing to do with Dependency Injection.

Comment: They're awfully close.  See: [Is dependency injection just another name for the strategy pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/823387/1288) and [What is the difference between Strategy pattern and Dependency Injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176520/1288)

Comment: @Dipan: before going to downvote this, you better think about the answer five minutes.

Comment: it's true that Dependency Injection can be considered very similar to the Strategy Pattern, but when people say dependency injection they usually mean Inversion of Control, which I think is a lot more distinct from Strategy (esp. IoC container).

Comment: @DocBrown -about downvoting - of close to 550+ votes, i have hardly done 10 downvotes! I am not doing this unnecessarily. Also, the references that Bill provided, according to me are just based on same perception as what S.Lott shared here. But none are backed with any credible references. If S.Lott would have given any explanation, i would have even asked a question in comment but that is not the case either. Tomorrow now someone will quote *him* - that doesn't become truth!

Comment: "i would have even asked a question".  You can still ask.

Comment: *"but when people say dependency injection they usually mean Inversion of Control"* wow, that is putting a lot of assumptive meaning into something that just isn't there. Projecting your bias there just a little bit?

Comment: +1 Dependency Injection is merely doing the Strategy pattern with a fancy framework such as Spring.

Comment: DI is more of a creational pattern. It creates and injects strategies. Saying it's a strategy is just half the truth. DI is more a microkernel pattern! I can't believe people upvote this. Strategy is more like a trait of good DI, not a necessity.

Comment: @Falcon: I'm not sure the question expected that kind of depth.  The question was superficial (and a bit of a complaint).  Strategy is a feature of numerous design patterns.

Comment: @MattDavey Dependency Injection is just one way of implementing Inversion of Control.  They're not the same thing.

Comment: Strategy and DI are not precisely the same, so without further explanation this answer is misleading.  -1 for "overrated".

Comment: @JarrodRoberson & Billy Lizard yes I know dependency injection and IoC are not the same thing, but the point I was making is that an awful lot of people (falsely) use them as equivalent terms.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: What are other ways of implementing inversion of control?

Comment: @TomAnderson Using a service locator is another.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Aha. I don't think of that as a kind of IoC, but i suppose it is really, as long as some external agent controls the binding service names to services.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dependency Injection is more relevant when separating implementation in tiers. Another area where we think about dependency injection is unit testing. And your pre-date suggestion seems to be correct. If the gang were to collect and segregate patterns in 2012, definitely dependency injection will be there.

Strategy could come up in discussions but Strategy does not talk about dependency injection. But when using strategy pattern in a single project or dll(all classes and interfaces remain in one project) it appears that we are doing dependency injection. In fact we are not.

Now, if the classes and interfaces mentioned in strategy pattern are separated in different projects or tiers then WE will have to use dependency injection techniques. We could use unity configuration files(no runtime change possible though). But Strategy pattern does not say how to inject a dependency.

If there is a pattern that resembles closely to Dependency injection then it is Abstract Factory Method pattern. This pattern could be used inside a strategy pattern to inject dependency.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please read the original question instead of replying to other answers :)

Answer (score -5):

the answer Strategy is 100% correct.  I up voted it but can comment.

"Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.[1] Strategy is one of the patterns included in the influential book Design Patterns by Gamma et al. that popularized the concept of using patterns to describe software design."

A design pattern is not dependent on its use.  Dependency Injection is implemented by using the Strategy pattern.  If we named each pattern based on the use case we would have to rename alot of patterns.

The repository pattern is not a new pattern, it is the Template Pattern.

"In the template method of this design pattern, one or more algorithm steps can be overridden by subclasses to allow differing behaviors while ensuring that the overarching algorithm is still followed."

Often the patterns are multiple patterns combined and named such as the MVC pattern.

The GOF didn't have interfaces the used Pure Abstract classes, and also took advantage of C++'s ability to inherit from more than one class.

Comment: The purpose of a pattern absolutely is important in distinguishing. Among GoF patterns, Adapter and Proxy are good examples - they have the same form, but different purpose. I'd also disagree with your assertion that DI is implemented using Strategy; Strategy is more specific in its purpose and the way the configured object is used, so it's more reasonable to say that Strategy is implemented with DI.